# Refer to a class without explicitly mentioning its namespace

Tags: ruby, namespaces

I have a class within several modules: `This::Is::A::Long::ClassName`. Is there any way, within one script or method, to make `ClassName` available without having to reference the namespace? Instead of writing:

```
This::Is::A::Long::ClassName.do_something
This::Is::A::Long::ClassName.do_something_else
This::Is::A::Long::ClassName.do_something_different
```

is anything as below possible?

```
include This::Is::A::Long
ClassName.do_something
ClassName.do_something_else
ClassName.do_something_different
```

Comment: You already have it. Try your code. It should work.

Comment: Eh... so it does. That's weird, I tried it before posting this question and I coulda *sworn* it didn't, maybe I made a mistake earlier. Now I feel stupid...

Comment: @GeorgeMillo an `include` is something different than being in the right namespace. So your code might work, but beware, your include could possibly overwrite methods.

Comment: @BeatRichartz It is true if the included module defines instance methods, when modules are used as namespaces, they are expected to define just constants and singleton methods.

Comment: @toro2k I am just advising against using `include` as a means to not write the whole namespaced class name in another namespace. Even if certain Ruby coding conventions are respected, it will put the module in that classes ancestor chain with all possible side effects.

Comment: @BeatRichartz You're completely right - I only want to use this in one particular script to avoid the hassle of writing `This::Is::A::Long` loads of times, where I know what I'm getting into and that I'm not overriding anything. I'd be extremely cautious about using `include` like this in a wider context. (Just figured I should point that out to anyone with the same question who comes here by Google in the future.)

Comment: @GeorgeMillo Well, the best way to tell everyone in the future that using `include` for your problem is a bad idea is to accept my answer as the right one. I don't care about the rep, but you should take a look at your problem and then decide which is the best answer. What about readability, which answer is clearer about what it does to fellow developers? Which answer is without potential side effects, shorter and even more effective? `include` is just not what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using modules for namespacing, the code you posted should work, see this example:

```
module Long
  module Name
    class ClassName
    end
  end
end

ClassName
# => ... uninitialized constant ClassName (NameError)

include Long::Name
ClassName
# => Long::Name::ClassName
```

Comment: Yeah, this is right. Don't know how I missed this before posting the question, I must have made a mistake when trying out my own example code. \*facepalm\*.

Answer (score 5):

Ruby has no equivalent to `C++`  `using namespace`, and you can not reference a class without being in the right namespace, but you can always make it a variable since a class is also an object

```
long_class = This::Is::A::Long::ClassName
long_class.do_something
long_class.do_something_else
# and so on
```

**EDIT**

An `include` does not put you in the right namespace, it includes the methods & classes in the module you are including (that is, it puts the module in the classes ancestors) and is therefore most certainly not suitable for your needs: Consider the following:

```
module This
  module Is
    module A

      def foo
        puts 'A#foo'
      end

      def bar
        puts 'A#bar'
      end

      class ClassName
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now, you may not want to write `This::Is::A::ClassName` in another class, let's say:

```
class C
  def foo
    puts 'C#foo'
  end
end

class B < C
  include This::Is::A
end
```

Now, `B.new.foo` still puts out `C#foo`, right? **Wrong**. Since you included the module, the method has been overwritten.

Comment: This is the reason, I think, why using modules both as namespaces and as mixins is definitely a bad idea.

Comment: @toro2k This is the reason why using `include` as some sort of shortcut to not to have to write out a namespace is a bad idea. Have you ever seen anyone doing `include ActiveRecord` because they did not want to write out `ActiveRecord::Base`?